# Why is my falling array value disappearing?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I have a 2D array in C and I am trying to make the positive or `1` value fall down till it reaches the bottom of the array but for some reason as soon as I run the code the `1` goes to the left and then down. The way it is meant to work is the current value is turned to `0` and the bottom value turns into a `1`, this is repeated and gives the effect of falling straight down, the code for this is in the `fallDown()` function.

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#ifdef __unix__
# include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
# include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * (x))
#endif

int sizeX = 20;
int sizeY = 20;

int grid[20][20] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

int fallDown(int grid[sizeX][sizeY], int x, int y){
    grid[x][y]=0;
 grid[x][y+1]=1;
}

int main(void){
 int neighbour_count[sizeX][sizeY];
    int x,y,iterations;

 for(iterations=0;iterations<500;iterations++){
  system("cls"); //Clear screen
  for(x=0;x<sizeX;x++){
    printf("\n");
    for(y=0;y<sizeY;y++){
     if(grid[x][y]==1){
      printf("@");
             }
    else{
      printf(" ");
    }
         }
  }
  for(y=0;y<sizeY;y++){
    for(x=0;x<sizeX;x++){
        if(grid[x][y] == 1){
         fallDown(grid, x, y);
    }
   }
        }
  printf("\n");
  sleep(1);
 }
}
```

Comment: `fallDown` doesn't have any bounds checking. With your loops it's possible that it will be called with `y == sizeY - 1`. Then `y + 1` will be out of bounds.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Still, I am just trying to understand why this weird behaviour of going left is happening and how to fix it. The problem of bounds is one I plan to solve later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `y` need to be swapped in `fallDown`.
In the second set of loops in `main` when a `1` is found, the loop must stop or the next execution of the `x` loop will `fallDown` again and again and again... until the loop finishes.
I am using Linux and had to use `clear` to clear the screen.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int sizeX = 20;
int sizeY = 20;

int grid[20][20] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

void fallDown(int grid[sizeX][sizeY], int x, int y){
    grid[x][y]=0;
    ++x;
    if ( x == 20) {
        x = 0; // back to top
    }
    grid[x][y]=1;
}

int main(void){
    int x,y,iterations;

    for(iterations=0;iterations<500;iterations++){
        system("clear"); //Clear screen
        for(x=0;x<sizeX;x++){
            printf("\n");
            for(y=0;y<sizeY;y++){
                if(grid[x][y]==1){
                    printf("@");
                }
                else{
                    printf(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        for(y=0;y<sizeY;y++){
            for(x=0;x<sizeX;x++){
                if(grid[x][y] == 1){
                    fallDown(grid, x, y);
                    y = sizeY;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int fallDown(int grid[sizeX][sizeY], int x, int y){
    grid[x][y] = 0;
    grid[x][y+1] = 1;
}
```

sizex is the number of rows and sizeY is the number of columns

So you should change fallDown function like this

```
int fallDown(int grid[sizeX][sizeY], int x, int y){
      if(x == 19 || grid[x][y] == 0) return;
      grid[x+1][y] = 1;
      grid[x][y] = 0;
}
```

Comment: It still does not work, it just stays still.

Comment: Now all it does is teleport to the bottom ignoring the `sleep(1)` function which is meant to slow it

Comment: Just swapping X and Y can solve the problem.

Comment: According to the structure of 2D array, X is meant to row, and Y is for column. We have to increase X to move down.

Comment: Which lines do I need to change, the lines in the fallDown function because when I do that the @ does not move, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use terminal escape codes.
(Provided the terminal supports them.)
This wraps the movement so if the `@` goes beyond the edge, it appears on the opposite edge. Not sure if this is what is wanted?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXROW 20
#define MAXCOL 20

typedef struct at_s {
    int row;
    int col;
} at_t;

void moveat ( at_t *at, int ud, int rl) {
    // moves up down right left diagonal
    at->row += ud;
    if ( at->row > MAXROW) {
        at->row = 1;
    }
    if ( at->row < 1) {
        at->row = MAXROW;
    }
    at->col += rl;
    if ( at->col > MAXCOL) {
        at->col = 1;
    }
    if ( at->col < 1) {
        at->col = MAXCOL;
    }
}

void showat ( at_t at, int show) {
    printf ( "\033[%d;%dH%c", at.row, at.col, show);
    fflush ( stdout);
}

int main ( void) {
    int chgrow = 0;
    int chgcol = 0;
    at_t at = { 4, 12};

    srand ( time ( NULL));
    printf ( "\033[2J");//clear screen

    for ( int moving = 0; moving < 500; ++moving) {
        showat ( at, ' ');
        chgrow = rand ( ) % 3; // range of 0 1 or 2
        --chgrow; // range is now -1 0 or 1

        chgcol = rand ( ) % 3;
        --chgcol;
        moveat ( &at, chgrow, chgcol);
        showat ( at, '@');
        printf ( "\033[22;1H\n");
        sleep ( 1);
    }

    printf ( "\033[22;1H\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simpler answer, all you need to do is to do is update the screen every time you move the `@`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#ifdef __unix__
# include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
# include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * (x))
#endif

int sizeX = 20;
int sizeY = 20;

int grid[20][20] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
                    
int drawScreen(int x, int y){
    system("cls"); //Clear screen
  for(x=0;x<sizeX;x++){
    printf("\n");
    for(y=0;y<sizeY;y++){
     if(grid[x][y]==1){
      printf("@");
     }
    else{
     printf(" ");
    }
   }
  }
}

int main(void){
 int x,y,iterations;

 for(iterations=0;iterations<10;iterations++){
    for(y=0;y<sizeY;y++){
        for(x=0;x<sizeX;x++){
            if(grid[y][x] >= 1){
                grid[y][x] = 0;
                grid[y+1][x] = 1;
                drawScreen(x,y);
                break;
      }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
}
```